# Calculate euclidean distance with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a point set which I have stored its coordinates in three different arrays (xa, ya, za). Now, I want to calculate the euclidean distance between each point of this point set (xa[0], ya[0], za[0] and so on) with all the points of an another point set (xb, yb, zb) and  every time store the minimum distance in a new array.

Let's say that xa.shape = (11,), ya.shape = (11,), za.shape= (11,). Respectively, xb.shape = (13,), yb.shape = (13,), zb.shape = (13,). What I want to do is to take each time one xa[],ya[],za[], and calculate its distance with all the elements of xb, yb, zb, and at the end store the minimum value into an xfinal.shape = (11,) array.

Do you think that this would be possible with numpy?

Comment: In other words, for each `xa/ya/za`, you'd like to compute the distance to the nearest point in `xb/yb/zb`?

Comment: Yes, if it would be easier somehow...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A different solution would be to use the spatial module from scipy, the KDTree in particular.

This class learn from a set of data and can be interrogated given a new dataset:

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree
# create some fake data
x = arange(20)
y = rand(20)
z = x**2
# put them togheter, should have a form [n_points, n_dimension]
data = np.vstack([x, y, z]).T
# create the KDTree
kd = KDTree(data)
```

now if you have a point you can ask the distance and the index of the closet point (or the N closest points) simply by doing:

```
kd.query([1, 2, 3])
# (1.8650720813822905, 2)
# your may differs
```

or, given an array of positions:

```
#bogus position
x2 = rand(20)*20
y2 = rand(20)*20
z2 = rand(20)*20
# join them togheter as the input
data2 = np.vstack([x2, y2, z2]).T
#query them
kd.query(data2)

#(array([ 14.96118553,   9.15924813,  16.08269197,  21.50037074,
#    18.14665096,  13.81840533,  17.464429  ,  13.29368755,
#    20.22427196,   9.95286671,   5.326888  ,  17.00112683,
#     3.66931946,  20.370496  ,  13.4808055 ,  11.92078034,
#     5.58668204,  20.20004206,   5.41354322,   4.25145521]),
#array([4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]))
```

Comment: Vastly superior to other answers, you can also use cKDTree which is much faster (with new scipy it may be the same).

Comment: Ok, apparently, this option works better. However, at the end I don't know whether this will work in abaqus where I am running those scripts. Do you know how I could extract the array with the minimum values from kd.query? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Ok I did it. It was not so difficult. Thanks a lot once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the difference from each xa to each xb with `np.subtract.outer(xa, xb)`. The distance to the nearest xb is given by

```
np.min(np.abs(np.subtract.outer(xa, xb)), axis=1)
```

To extend this to 3D,

```
distances = np.sqrt(np.subtract.outer(xa, xb)**2 + \
    np.subtract.outer(ya, yb)**2 + np.subtract.outer(za, zb)**2)
distance_to_nearest = np.min(distances, axis=1)
```

If you actually want to know *which* of the b points is the nearest, you use `argmin` in place of `min`.

```
index_of_nearest = np.argmin(distances, axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes, I think that it works. It seems very fast. My arrays are huge! Therefore, I thought that I had to iterate through the xa,ya,za length by taking each row and calculate its distance with whole xb,yb,zb. I think it works. I ll cross check its validity and I ll let you know. Thank you very very much anyway!

Comment: If you can use scipy, see @EnricoGiampieri's colution.

Comment: Unfortunately, it says that array is too big. It seems that it doesn't work for my arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way of doing this. Most importantly, there's a trade-off between memory-usage and speed. Here's the wasteful method:

```
s = (1, -1)
d = min((xa.reshape(s)-xb.reshape(s).T)**2
     + (ya.reshape(s)-yb.reshape(s).T)**2
     + (za.reshape(s)-zb.reshape(s).T)**2), axis=0)
```

The other method would be to iterate over the point set in `b` to avoid the expansion to the full blown matrix.