# Find closest point to another point with NumPy and/or SciPy quickly

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I want to know the fastest way in python to calculate the closest point in a list of points to my point. There is already [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435551/calculate-euclidean-distance-with-numpy), but it does not consider performance and there are the following extra details:

- There are many, many points (hundreds of thousands)
- The data is already divided into segments, if there are any optimizations applicable to that
- SciPy is OK, but only if it is faster

**EDIT:** I simply need to find the closest point, and the segments are just roughly equally long sublists of points.

**EDIT 2:** Changed question topic from distance to closest point.

Comment: Is it possible that you could do some scaled tests with like 1000 points with different methods you have researched?

Comment: Ok, so calculating the closest points (see `scipy.spatial.cKDTree`) is a very different task from calculating distances. I'm still confused about the segments: are you looking for nearest points between segments, within segments, etc? Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: @rth I know the point is on a (nonlinear) line, and it is divided into segments of points each roughly the same length, and I want to find the point on that line that is the closest, not knowing which segment it is on. (The segments are for other computational purposes, but it might help hasten this calculation too.)

Comment: @rth Hmm, thanks. Read that question before, but that confirmed that that was also that fastest way.